# Freemarker: Nested Macro using a variable

Tags: macros, nested, freemarker

I'm having an issue getting some code to work that I'm hoping someone out there might be able to help me with.

Basically, we have a nest macro that returns an *image ID*.
This code works fine when using a static value.  However, if I use a variable, it fails.

Works: `[@imageIDByPath]Brand/header.jpg[/@imageIDByPath]`

Fails: `[@imageIDByPath]Brand/${imageName}[/@imageIDByPath]`

Is there a way to make this work without updating the macro?  sadly I don't have control over the macro to make any changes to it.

I've tried:

```
[#assign imageName = "Header.jpg"]
[#assign imageIDMacro][#noparse][@imageIDByPath]Brand/[/#noparse]${imagename}[#noparse][/@imageIDByPath][/#noparse][/#assign]
[#assign imageID = imageIDMacro?interpret]
[@imageID /]
```

but this doesn't appear to work either.

any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: It should work, except that you have a typo: `imagename` instead of `imageName` in the `${...}` Also, I'm not sure what's up with the complication with `#noparse` and `?interpret`, as it's redundant in your example.

Comment: Thanks ddekany.  after doing some more digging into this, it seems to be an issue with the freemarker within the platform we are using.